# Uninstalling the components while sys shutdown or logoff

Tags: c#, winforms, uninstallation, shutdown, logoff

We have components created in .Net and installed in user systems. We were able to create a form and invoke the same in Uninstall method of Installer class to prompt for a password while user tries to uninstall from the control Panel. We added the exe (which has Installer class implemented and custom code written in Uninstall overridden method) as custom action during msi (setup) file creation.

Using this msi file for setup installs the component successfully and when user tries to uninstall from control Panel, system is prompting for password as required and getting uninstalled only if password is correct else it is throwing an exception and uninstall process is not successful.

One issue we face is, when user tries to uninstall and form is displayed, when user tries to shutdown or log off, it automatically closes the form and uninstalls the component even without password is provided. We tried to check if it is force shutdown and raise normal Exception (also tried InstallerException) still program is getting uninstalled.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Form.Closing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx) event.
When form is closing and credentials is bad you can break uninstall process.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But when we try to throw exception in Form.closing event and force log out or shutdown with the exception window open, still the component gets uninstalled although exception is thrown